# ES6 imports doesn't work

Tags: javascript

`b.js`:

```
const x = 1;
export {x};
```

`a.js`:

```
import {x} from 'b'; // <<-- ERROR
console.log(x);
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="a.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

I'm using WebStorm and running the project in Chrome in Win7.

---

## Update:

I changed `index.html` content to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="a.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "b". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
>   [image]

It seems that `b.js` is not loaded.

Comment: You need to include `type="module"` in your script tag. And the other resource (`b.js`) has to be available to the page.

Comment: the issue is likely that for ES6 modules to work in javascript, you need the `type="module"` attribute on the script tag

Comment: Webstorm has nothing to do with this. It's just an IDE. It won't actually run the code

Comment: `<script src="a.js" type="module"></script>`

Comment: @AshishGaur not even close to a duplicate

Comment: seriously, all you need is `type="module"`

Comment: @JaromandaX It doesn't work. I guess I'm missing something here. I updated the question.

Comment: sorry, didn't read `a.js` ... `import {x} from './b.js'`

Comment: It seems that my comment ended in the void. I should be more specific next time...

Comment: to be honest, @KarelG I did not see your comment (only the one after it) when I first came to this thread

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use ES6 modules, you have to load the script using `type="module"` - this ensures that browsers that do not understand ES6 modules won't choke on it

Next, to import, you must specify path and full filename of the imported file

See comments in code

### b.js

```
const x = 1;
export {x};
```

### a.js

```
// specify the path and full filename below
import {x} from './b.js'; // <<-- NO ERROR NOW
console.log(x);
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- add type="module" -->
<script src="a.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working. Why do I need to add `./` and `.js`? I didn't see that in the docs of Mozilla.

Comment: do you see docs in mozilla that say you can leave the file extension off?

Comment: Huh? It is clearly in the docs that you have to specify file names. Please check the description of `module-name` in this doc: [`import syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: My bad. I was completely wrong. Thank you for your help. (I don't see that Mozilla added the `.` in the prefix. - Why?)

Comment: `This is often a relative or absolute path name` ... relative paths start with at least `.` ... absolute paths start with `/` ... so there must be a path component to the name as far as I read into it - it's not clear unless you know this about relative and absolute paths of course

Answer (score 0):

set "type": "module" in the package.json or
use the .mjs extension.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).